# Thread in constructor... bad practice?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have something along the lines of..

```
    private UavControlForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (ControlFacade.CheckIfStkIsLaunched())
        {
            _controlFacade = new ControlFacade();
            SubscribeToStkQuit();
        }
        else
        {
            Thread tExitUavController = new Thread(ExitUavController);
            tExitUavController.IsBackground = true;
            tExitUavController.Start();
        }             
    }

    private void ExitUavController()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        ForceCloseAtBeginning();
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void ForceCloseAtBeginning()
    {
        DialogResult dlgResult = 
            MessageBox.Show("STK application not running. UavController will now close.", "Closing...",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
```

The thread is used to ensure the WinForm is fully initialised before attempting the exit. This seems like bad practice to me... how can I better implement such functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would extract the logic of checking for whether STK application is running to outside of the form and only initialize the form if the application is running.

But if you're trying to ensure that the form fully initializes before it closes, then either override the form's closing event or hook onto it, and cancel the closing if the STK application is not running.

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e) {
    if (!ControlFacade.CheckIfStkIsLaunched()) {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    base.OnClosing(e);
}
```

Comment: @WulfgarPro: Glad to help! Will provided an example of what I was suggesting below.

Answer (score 2):

You should implement your own Main method for your application. Within the project settings, tell the application to use this method, instead of starting the Form.

Within this Main method, you would perform the check for whether the external application is running, and if so - then run the Form.

Example:

```
static void Main()
{
  if (!ControlFacade.CheckIfStkIsLaunched())
  { 

        DialogResult dlgResult = 
            MessageBox.Show("STK application not running. UavController will now close.", "Closing...",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

        Application.Exit();
        return;
  } 

  Application.Run(new UavControlForm());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just override the OnLoad method in the Form and then do the check?

Comment: I think he wants to ensure that the forms is ready to load prior to allowing it to close. Overriding the OnLoad method will not help him if the form closes prior to the OnLoad event.

Comment: I don't think a form can be closed before it is loaded.

Comment: +1 for @Richard Schneider. The Form will not process message queue until it is fully loaded (unless you take a suecide dive into DoEvents() from Form_Load). Any "close" message/action from a user would come in the form of a SendMessage put in the message queue by Windows and won't be processed by the GUI thread (in ANY part of the application) until the form is fully loaded.